# What's up with the spring-jdbc-3.2.0.RELEASE manifest?

Tags: spring-jdbc

It's completely empty compared to the spring-jdbc-3.1.3.RELEASE manifest.

Did spring-jdbc suddenly lose all it's dependencies? Cool.

Actually not so cool - since we've enabled auto-upgrading of Spring in our Maven pom, it caused a compilation error on our Jenkins CI

Comment: Diff in IntelliJ: [link](http://i48.tinypic.com/2liu7p4.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is intentional. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/migration-3.2.html#migration-3.2-osgi-users for details.

Answer (score 0):

JSYK, another cryptic error:

```
ERROR DataNucleus.Enhancer - DataNucleus Enhancer completed with an error. Please review the enhancer log for full details. Some classes may have been enhanced but some caused errors
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Errors were encountered when loading the specified MetaData files and classes. See the nested exceptions for details
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadClasses(MetaDataManager.java:536) ~[datanucleus-core-3.1.4.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.getFileMetadataForInput(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:734) ~[datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:525) ~[datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1258) ~[datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at org.datanucleus.maven.AbstractDataNucleusMojo.executeInJvm(AbstractDataNucleusMojo.java:333) [maven-datanucleus-plugin-3.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.maven.AbstractEnhancerMojo.enhance(AbstractEnhancerMojo.java:250) [maven-datanucleus-plugin-3.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.maven.AbstractEnhancerMojo.executeDataNucleusTool(AbstractEnhancerMojo.java:67) [maven-datanucleus-plugin-3.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.maven.AbstractDataNucleusMojo.execute(AbstractDataNucleusMojo.java:126) [maven-datanucleus-plugin-3.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537) [maven-embedder-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196) [maven-embedder-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141) [maven-embedder-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:653) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:460) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:286) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:222) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:69) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:52) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3070) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3029) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(AnnotationType.java:113) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:66) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:202) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:69) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:52) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3070) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3050) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AnnotationManagerImpl.getMetaDataForClass(AnnotationManagerImpl.java:128) ~[datanucleus-core-3.1.4.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadAnnotationsForClass(MetaDataManager.java:2650) ~[datanucleus-core-3.1.4.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadClasses(MetaDataManager.java:496) ~[datanucleus-core-3.1.4.jar:na]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

Was solved by adding dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```